# Deleting An Unwanted, Unused Slide

Tags: slideshows

In the process of creating a SlideShow, I have managed to add a slide that I now want to remove.  However, the slide now has no title, nor do the right=hand bars signifying the presence of a cell appear that one might be able to delete.  I believe this blank was created when I highlighted some code, copied it and moved it to another similarly structured slide, thus leaving a "whole" in the presentation.  A page for the slide (ie a "slide") remains but contains no content.

How does one delete such a "dead" slide in such a case?

Perhaps the question might be rephrased, is there a SlideShow Function not presently visible, stored in the presentation, that could be modified to delete this "blanK" slide?

The Slide before looks like this (sans output, which of course follows)

```
img1 = ImageAdd[Import["Georges_Cuvier.jpg", ImageSize -> 200], 0.20];
img2 = ImageAdd[
Import["Achille_Valenciennes01.jpg", 
ImageSize -> {1600, 2000}], -.03];
disk = Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 0}, {8, 12.0}]}];
img2 = ImageAdd[img2, disk];
text1a = Text[
Style[ToString["Jean Léopold Nicolas Frédéric Cuvier"], 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 22]];
text1b = Text[
Style[ToString["(23 August 1769 - 13 May 1832)"], 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 16]];
text2a = Text[
Style[ToString["Achille Valenciennes"], FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
Bold, 22]];
text2b = Text[
Style[ToString["(9 August 1794 - 13 April 1865)"], 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 16]];
Grid[Transpose@{{ImageResize[img1, 700], text1a, 
text1b}, {ImageResize[img2, 700], text2a, text2b}}, 
ItemSize -> {30, Full}]
```

The slide that is blank is simply empty except for the slide style background.  The cursor appears as a input horizontal bar.

The slide that follows looks like this (sans output graphics), which of course would follow)  The first line is a title as per slideshow style, followed by the code [and output not shown]:

Discoverers of "Biodiversity"

```
disk = Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 0}, {8, 12.0}]}];
img1Bleeker = 
ImageCrop[ImageAdd[
Import["Pieter-Bleeker-1819-1878.jpg", ImageSize -> 1000], 0.010], 600, 
Bottom];
img1Bleeker = ImageAdd[img1Bleeker, disk];
img2Gunther = 
ImageCrop[ImageAdd[
Import["Gunther_Albert_1830-1914.png", ImageSize -> {800, 1000}], -.03], 
700, Bottom];
img2Gunther = ImageAdd[img2Gunther, disk];
img3Boulenger = 
ImageAdd[Import["Boulenger_George_1858-1937.png", 
ImageSize -> {750, 1100}], -.03]; img3Boulenger = 
ImageAdd[img3Boulenger, disk];
img4Steindachner = 
ImageAdd[Import["Steindachner_Franz_1834-1919.png", 
ImageSize -> {1600, 2000}], -.03];
img4Steindachner = ImageAdd[img4Steindachner, disk];
text1aBleeker = 
Text[Style[ToString["Pieter Bleeker"], FontFamily ->  "Helvetica", Bold, 
22 ]];
text1bBleeker = 
Text[Style[ToString["(10 July 1819- 24 January 1878)"], 
FontFamily ->  "Helvetica", Bold, 16]];
text2aGunther = 
Text[Style[ToString["Albert Gunther" ], FontFamily ->  "Helvetica", Bold, 
22]];
text2bGunther = 
Text[Style[ToString["(3 October 1830-1 February 1914)"], 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 16]];
text3aBoulenger = 
Text[Style[ToString["George Boulenger"], FontFamily ->  "Helvetica", Bold, 
22]];
text3bBoulenger = 
Text[Style[ToString["(19 October 1858-23 November 1937)"], 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 16]];
text4aSteindachner = 
Text[Style[ToString["Franz Steindachner"], FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 
22]];
text4bSteindachner = 
Text[Style[ToString["(11 November 1834-10 December 1919)"], 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 16]];
Grid[Partition[#, 
2] &@(*2 is number of desired columns*)(Column[#, 
  Alignment -> Center] & /@ {{ImageResize[img1Bleeker, 700], 
  text1aBleeker, text1bBleeker}, {ImageResize[img2Gunther, 700], 
  text2aGunther, text2bGunther}, {ImageResize[img3Boulenger, 700], 
  text3aBoulenger, text3bBoulenger}, {ImageResize[img4Steindachner, 500], 
  text4aSteindachner, text4bSteindachner}}), ItemSize -> {30}]
```

Comment: Could you show a screen shot of such a "dead" slide, including the cells before and after it?

Comment: The Slide before looks like this:

Comment: Looks like *what*?

Answer (score 2):

While editing all slides are separated by a small gray "space-holder".

Suppose you have 6 slides and you want to delete the 5th, which is your empty one.

Within the "space-holder" between slide 4 and 5 you can click on the (outermost) cell bracket (being for the fifth slide [becoming visible as you move the pointer to the border]).

Choosing this cell bracket and and deleting it, deletes the 5th slide.